# como Insertar datos de archivo CSV a DataGridView con Drag Drop en C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, drag-and-drop

Tengo un archivo CSV , quiero arrastrarlo a un DataGridView y que se inserten los datos, ya tengo los eventos generados y la propiedad "allow to drop" activada, pero solo logro recuperar la direccion del archivo de esta forma: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los eventos los tengo configurados de esta manera:

```
        private void dataGridView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        //Revisa si el formato de los datos del archivo puede ser aceptado
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {

            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
        else
        {

            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }
```

y el siguiente para el drop

```
private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {

            string[] fileList = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop); 
            
            if ((e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Move))
            {
                string[] s = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s[i]);

            }

        }
    }
```

Pero solo obtengo el resultado mostrado arriba y no encuentro como leer la informacion dentro del archivo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando tu ejemplo de base, cree el siguiente ejemplo. Mi CSV es el siguiente:

```
1,Luis
2,Marco
```

entonces, tengo un `form` con un `DataGridView` (llamado `dgvNombres`) con 2 columnas, `ID` y `Nombre` :
[image: DataGridView]

en él, sólo utilicé el método DragEnter(), dejándolo de la siguiente manera:

```
private void dgvNombres_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            //Revisamos que sea un archivo
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                //Obtenemos el listado de directorios de archivos que se hayan obtenido
                string[] paths = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
                //ahora, por cada fichero, leemos y llenamos columnas
                foreach (var path in paths)
                {
                    //usamos streamreader
                    var reader = new StreamReader(path);
                    //recorremos
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        //leemos la línea
                        var line = reader.ReadLine();
                        //dependiendo tu CSV, aquí cambia el caracter que delimita cada campo
                        var values = line.Split(',');
                        //finalmente, añade cada valor obtenido mediante el split al grid
                        dgvNombres.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(values[0]), values[1]);
                    }
                    //ordenamos los resultados recién añadidos
                    dgvNombres.Sort(dgvNombres.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
                }
            }
        }
```

Observaciones importantes:

1. No estoy validando que el CSV sea válido
2. No estoy controlando excepciones
3. Los añade automáticamente al poner el csv dentro del grid, si te equivocas, tendrías que crear un método para "limpiar" el grid o algo similar
4. Puedes añadir múltiples CSV a la vez

Espero que mi respuesta te sea útil. ¡Saludos! :D

**Edit**

Anexo una captura de pantalla de como queda el resultado final:
[image: Resultado final]

Como observación adicional, noté que no se ordenaba correctamente mi datagrid, ya que todo se estaba llenando mediante strings, así que cambié 2 lineas en el código, para considerar que se ordene al terminar de llenarse el datagridview, y que inserte el primer dato como int.

Comment: Ex-ce-len-te! +1 si funciona. Tal vez sea cosa mía, tienes un screenshot del producto final, es decir, del DGV con las celdas y los textos del CSV?

Comment: listo :D ya debe de quedar

Comment: Muchas gracias. Excelente respuesta!